# If $ f(x) = f(x+1) $ and $ f''(x) + f(x) = \frac {1} { f( x+ \frac{3}{4}) } $ then $ f(x) = f( x+ \frac{1}{4}) $

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying to solve following problem. 
Let $ f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R $ be a twice differentiable function such that $ f(x) = f(x+1) $ for all $x$. If $$ f''(x) + f(x) = \frac {1} { f( x+ \frac{3}{4}) } $$ holds for all x . Then prove that $ f(x) = f( x+ \frac{1}{4})  $ for all $x$      To sove this problem i replaced $x$ by $x + \frac {1}{4} $ in $ f''(x) + f(x) = \frac {1} { f( x+ \frac{3}{4}) } $ so i got $ f''(x + \frac{1}{4}) + f(x + \frac{1}{4}) = \frac {1} { f( x+ 1) }$ =$ \frac{1}{ f( x) } $. I got stuck here how to proceed further. Thanx for your help.

Comment: @MartinR Do we have $f(x)=1$ ?

Comment: @Mister.Expandead how can u guarantee no other function will satisfy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try it : We put $x=\ln(y)$ and $y\neq 0$

The equality :$$ f''(x) + f(x) = \frac {1} { f( x+ \frac{3}{4}) } $$

Becomes :

$$\frac{f''(\ln(y))-f'(\ln(y))}{y^2}+f(\ln(y))=\frac{1}{f(\ln(y)+0.75)}$$

Now we assume $$f''(\ln(y))-f'(\ln(y))\neq 0\quad \forall y\neq 0$$

But :
$$\frac{f''(\ln(y))-f'(\ln(y))}{y^2}+f(\ln(y))=\frac{1}{f(\ln(y)+0.75)}=\frac{1}{f(\ln(y)+0.75+1)}=\frac{f''(\ln(y)+1)-f'(\ln(y)+1)}{y^2e^2}+f(\ln(y)+1)$$

Or :

$$\frac{f''(\ln(y))-f'(\ln(y))}{y^2}+f(\ln(y))=\frac{f''(\ln(y)+1)-f'(\ln(y)+1)}{y^2e^2}+f(\ln(y)+1)$$

Wich implies $$\frac{1}{y^2e^2}=\frac{1}{y^2}$$
Wich is a contradiction .

So we deduce that :

$$\frac{f''(\ln(y))-f'(\ln(y))}{y^2}=0 \quad \forall y\neq 0$$

Wich implies $f(\ln(y))=Constant$

Comment: wow. it's amazing. i want to know one thing that how you thought to put x = ln (y).